# Who bid for Mjolnir?

Tags: supernatural, mythology, mjolnir

In the latest episode of supernatural *Season 8, Episode 2 - What's Up, Tiger Mommy?*, who do we see bidding for Mjolnir? I strongly suspect that it was Loki, one of the few I can think of that would 'remember' the weapon. Am I right? We haven't seen Loki already in Supernatural, have we?

Comment: Didn't the Trickster/Gabriel pose as Loki while he was in hiding? I think the best I can say is we *may* have seen Loki already, depending on whether Gabriel and Loki were always the same person or Gabriel simply borrowed the identity.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes, see 5x19, [Hammer of the Gods](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Hammer_of_the_Gods).. Actually, quite an interesting name for the episode considering it took place in the [Elysian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elysium) Fields Hotel, and this question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the supernatural wiki, the being in question is [Vili](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Mr_Vili).

> 'In Norse mythology, Vili and Vé are the brothers of Óðinn (often Anglicized Odin), sons of Bestla, daughter of Bölþorn, and Borr, son of Búri.'

All I can find on him is that he gave, according to norse legend, the first man and woman their intelligence.

Comment: I thought he seemed a bit old for Loki, but wasn't familiar enough with Norse myth to make a decent guess as to who it was.

Answer (score 3):

The "old man" we see bidding for Mjolnir in that episode was indeed intended to be Vili as shown in the end credits.  He is one of Odin's brothers which explains the previous connection to the hammer.  As mentioned, there is also lore of Vili, Ve, and Odin slaying a Frost Giant together.  This explains why he has the finger.

Answer (score 0):

Loki was actually included as the trickster/archangel Gabriel. I assumed the bidder for the Hammer was Thor or possibly the Dwarf that made it. But for certain it wasn't Loki. I am not certain that they provided any decent clues to determine who the character was supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Remember how Gabriel was undercover or hiding from all the gods, who thought he was loki but he wasn't? He had a finger of a ice giant which relates to Loki.

Because of this I'm sure the bidder is loki; he always wanted the hammer (in norse mythology at least) he has access to ice giants even in the comic (Marvel?) he helps thor  to battle the ice giant (I forget the name he called him in the show).

I'm sure of it. Everything falls in place to easy and with that season being all about gods well, it seems to fit nicely.

Comment: and loki is a shape shifter so thats y he could be old.

Answer (score 0):

His name in the credits is Mr. Vili so duh, not Loki. Vili. It says it in the episode. He and Odin and Va killed the original frost giant, that's why he had the finger.